# 'No data to report' when i execute coverage report

Tags: django-testing

I use django.test to do unittest

At first i run

```
coverage run ./manage.py test audit.lib.tests.test_prune
```

And works well

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.493s

OK
```

But when i run `coverage report`, unexpected happens, it should show some reports as expected, but `No data to report`

```
root@0553f9cad609:/opt/buildaudit# coverage report
No data to report.
```

I have no ideas, it has confused me whole day.. Thank you all!

Comment: It's because i didn't execute `coverage combine`

Comment: This was my problem too.  I was seeing coverage results being generated (_sqlite3_ files with measurements from the expected source), but `coverage report` kept complaining there was no data.  I expect your fix affects anyone using `parallel=True`, as I am.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jim you should make an answer out of this - solved my problem and was the one help I found!

Answer (score 1):

Some of my tests executed helper programs, and I wanted to gather coverage results for those programs too.  That meant `coverage` had to gather and store metrics in multiple processes at the same time.  Normally, it stores them in a single file named *.coverage*, which doesn't work when gathering metrics in parallel.  Instead, `coverage` needs to be told to store results in separate files, one per process, giving them unique file names.  [Per the docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.4.1/cmd.html#combining-data-files-coverage-combine), that can be done by adding this to *.coveragerc*.

```ini
[run]
parallel = True
```

The report generators, like `coverage html`, expect those results to be combined into a single file.  That can be done by running this after the tests have finished, and before trying to create a report from them.

```bash
% coverage combine
```

Not doing so produces the *No data to report* error in the question.  Credit goes to @PengQunZhong for first suggesting this.

---

Going beyond the question a bit, this actually wasn't enough for me to get measurements from all sub-processes.  [The docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.3.2/subprocess.html) have a good description of the subtleties and solutions, but I'll summarize what I chose.  I use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module to start some of the sub-processes, so I had to add the following in the `[run]` section of *.coveragerc*.

```ini
concurrency = multiprocessing
```

Also, sub-processes needed to tell `coverage` to gather metrics since, unlike top-level tests, sub-processes are not run by `coverage`.  I did this by adding the following at the top of the code for each sub-process.  See the reference for other options.

```python
    import os
    if "COVERAGE_PROCESS_START" in os.environ:
        import coverage
        coverage.process_startup()
```

The environment variable used here is recognized by `coverage`; don't rename it.  Also, I ran my tests with the following.  I use [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/), but other test frameworks would be done similarly.  There's also a `pytest` [plug-in](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io) that can help.

```bash
% COVERAGE_PROCESS_START=.coveragerc coverage run pytest
```

Finally, some tests and their sub-processes needed small changes to ensure `coverage` was allowed to save its results when the process was terminated.  An ungraceful exit, `SIGKILL`, etc. prevent this.  `coverage` writes its results in an [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) hook, and if you have `coverage` 6.3 or newer, also in a signal handler for `SIGTERM`.  If your sub-processes are terminated any other way, `coverage` will not be able to save its results.  In my case, I usually sent a `SIGTERM` to the sub-process from its parent.   A parent that used [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) objects, for example, did this.

```python
kid.terminate()
```